# Is SonarQube analysis incremental or?

Tags: sonarqube

We have a process to check-in PL/SQL store procedures changes into TFS, then I use a Jenkins job to analysis them with SonarQube PL/SQL plugin. I see it always index all files (162). How does SonarQube Runner update the result to the database? Delete the existing one and create a new one, or update incrementally?

```
Getting version 'C378149' to 'D:\public_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube-PLSQL-TFS'...
Finished getting version 'C378149'.
[SonarQube-PLSQL-TFS] $ D:\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.4\bin\sonar-runner.bat -e -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://ip:5432/sonar ******** ******** -Dsonar.host.url=http://sonarqube.dev.com/ ******** ******** -Dsonar.projectBaseDir=D:\public_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube-PLSQL-TFS -Dsonar.language=plsql "-Dsonar.projectName=PL/SQL :: Schedule Snapshot 2013 :: EDBDEV" -Dsonar.projectVersion=1.0 -Dsonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8 -Dsonar.projectKey=PLSQL.EDBDEV -Dsonar.sources=ACCT/PROCEDURE,ADMIN/PROCEDURE,ADMINDBA/PROCEDURE,DMBO/PROCEDURE,DS/PROCEDURE,EQDRV/PROCEDURE,ETL/PROCEDURE,FAME/PROCEDURE,FIQR/PROCEDURE,FIRVFO/PROCEDURE,GLOBAL/PROCEDURE,IPA/PROCEDURE,IT/PROCEDURE,MKT/PROCEDURE,MREF/PROCEDURE,OMS/SEQUENCE,PA/PROCEDURE,PA_UAT/PROCEDURE,PCONFO/PROCEDURE,PRC/PROCEDURE,REC/PROCEDURE,RISK/PROCEDURE,VREP/SEQUENCE
D:\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.4
SonarQube Runner 2.4
Java 1.8.0_31 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
Windows Server 2012 R2 6.3 amd64
INFO: Error stacktraces are turned on.
INFO: Runner configuration file: D:\sonar-runner\sonar-runner-2.4\conf\sonar-runner.properties
INFO: Project configuration file: NONE
INFO: Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Work directory: D:\public_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube-PLSQL-TFS\.sonar
INFO: SonarQube Server 5.1
14:28:24.824 INFO  - Load global repositories
14:28:25.315 INFO  - Load global repositories (done) | time=498ms
14:28:25.321 INFO  - Server id: 20160208114216
14:28:25.327 INFO  - User cache: C:\Users\svc_selfserv_dev\.sonar\cache
14:28:25.350 INFO  - Install plugins
14:28:25.826 INFO  - Install JDBC driver
14:28:25.838 INFO  - Create JDBC datasource for jdbc:postgresql://ip:5432/sonar
14:28:27.873 INFO  - Initializing Hibernate
14:28:29.618 INFO  - views plugin licensed to OTPP, EVALUATION [Expiration: 2016-02-19, Server: *]
14:28:30.213 INFO  - Load project repositories
14:28:31.117 INFO  - Load project repositories (done) | time=904ms
14:28:31.118 INFO  - Load project settings
14:28:31.937 INFO  - Load technical debt model
14:28:32.033 INFO  - Apply project exclusions
14:28:33.795 WARN  - SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
14:28:33.799 INFO  - -------------  Scan PL/SQL :: Schedule Snapshot 2013 :: EDBDEV
14:28:33.832 INFO  - Load module settings
14:28:34.298 INFO  - Language is forced to plsql
14:28:34.324 INFO  - Load rules
14:28:34.945 INFO  - Base dir: D:\public_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube-PLSQL-TFS
14:28:34.946 INFO  - Working dir: D:\public_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube-PLSQL-TFS\.sonar
14:28:34.958 INFO  - Source paths: ACCT/PROCEDURE, ADMIN/PROCEDURE, ADMINDBA/PROCEDURE, DMBO/PROCEDURE, DS/PROCEDURE, EQDRV/PROCEDURE, ETL/PROCEDURE, FAME/PROCEDURE, FIQR/PROCEDURE, FIRVFO/PROCEDURE, GLOBAL/PROCEDURE, IPA/PROCEDURE, IT/PROCEDURE, MKT/PROCEDURE, MREF/PROCEDURE, OMS/SEQUENCE, PA/PROCEDURE, PA_UAT/PROCEDURE, PCONFO/PROCEDURE, PRC/PROCEDURE, REC/PROCEDURE, RISK/PROCEDURE, VREP/SEQUENCE
14:28:34.959 INFO  - Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_US
14:28:34.959 INFO  - Index files
14:28:35.274 INFO  - 162 files indexed
14:28:37.459 INFO  - Quality profile for plsql: Sonar way
14:28:38.372 INFO  - JIRA issues sensor will not run as some parameters are missing.
14:28:38.409 INFO  - plsql EVALUATION [Expiration: 2016-02-19, Server: *]
14:28:38.410 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor
14:28:38.528 INFO  - Sensor Lines Sensor (done) | time=118ms
14:28:38.529 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor
14:28:38.536 INFO  - Sensor QProfileSensor (done) | time=7ms
14:28:38.536 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor
14:28:39.221 INFO  - Sensor InitialOpenIssuesSensor (done) | time=685ms
14:28:39.222 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor
14:28:39.236 INFO  - Sensor ProjectLinksSensor (done) | time=14ms
14:28:39.236 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor
14:28:39.255 INFO  - Sensor VersionEventsSensor (done) | time=19ms
14:28:39.255 INFO  - Sensor com.sonar.plsql.plugin.K@4526b3d5
14:28:39.319 INFO  - 162 source files to be analyzed
14:28:39.823 WARN  - 
14:28:39.824 WARN  - Unable to fully parse: D:\public_jendevslave_1\workspace\DevOps\SonarQube-PLSQL-TFS\ADMIN\PROCEDURE\WINDOWS_MONITOR_FILE_SYS.prc
14:28:39.824 WARN  - Parse error starting from line 1
14:28:39.824 WARN  - 
14:28:41.390 INFO  - Sensor com.sonar.plsql.plugin.K@4526b3d5 (done) | time=2135ms
14:28:41.390 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor
14:28:41.391 INFO  - No SCM system was detected. You can use the 'sonar.scm.provider' property to explicitly specify it.
14:28:41.391 INFO  - Sensor SCM Sensor (done) | time=1ms
14:28:41.391 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor
14:28:41.391 INFO  - DefaultCpdEngine is used for plsql
14:28:41.392 INFO  - Cross-project analysis enabled
14:28:41.399 INFO  - 162/162 source files have been analyzed
14:28:46.099 INFO  - Sensor CPD Sensor (done) | time=4708ms
14:28:46.101 INFO  - No quality gate is configured.
14:28:46.194 INFO  - Compare to previous analysis (2016-02-08)
14:28:46.206 INFO  - Compare over 30 days (2016-01-09, analysis of Thu Feb 04 16:28:50 EST 2016)
14:28:46.764 INFO  - Execute decorators...
14:28:50.496 INFO  - Store results in database
14:28:55.612 INFO  - Analysis reports generated in 1041ms, dir size=1016 KB
14:28:58.352 INFO  - Analysis reports compressed in 2738ms, zip size=360 KB
14:28:58.605 INFO  - Analysis reports sent to server in 253ms
14:28:58.605 INFO  - ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://sonarqube.dev/dashboard/index/PLSQL.EDBDEV
14:28:58.605 INFO  - Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report.
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 35.693s
Final Memory: 20M/621M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Started calculate disk usage of build
Finished Calculation of disk usage of build in 0 seconds
Started calculate disk usage of workspace
Finished Calculation of disk usage of workspace in  1 second
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by `update the result` you mean `update the Issues` then [this page](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Differential+Views#DifferentialViews-DifferentialViewsonIssues) explains the algorithm used to determine whether an Issue is new or not.

In any case it is normal that all files are scanned. The whole project codebase is inspected and the project's code/issues/measures/etc. are updated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

When one runs a new analysis, SonarQube purges parts of the previous results, see 
[History and Events - SonarQube Documentation - SonarQube](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/History+and+Events)

> when you run a new analysis of your project, some data that was previously available is cleaned out of the database. For example the source code of the previous analysis, measures at directory and file levels, and so on are automatically be removed at the end of a new analysis. Additional, some old analysis snapshots are also removed
>   [...]
>
> To save space and to improve overall performance, the Database Cleaner deletes some rows in the database. Here is its default configuration:
>
> - For each project:
>
>   - only one snapshot per day is kept after 1 day. Snapshots marked by an event are not deleted.
>   - only one snapshot per week is kept after 1 month. Snapshots marked by an event are not deleted.
>   - only one snapshot per month is kept after 1 year. Snapshots marked by an event are not deleted.
>   - all snapshots older than 5 years are deleted, including snapshots marked by an event.
> - All closed issues more than 30 days old are deleted
> - History at package/directory level is not kept
>
> These settings can be changed at Settings > General Settings > General > Database Cleaner.

If you are concerned by the **performance** of running an analysis or you are wondering if all analysises are **persisted** (or volatile) bear in mind that in the log you posted you have run a full analysis (the default).
Overall, there are three types of analysis that SonarQube can perform:

- **full analysis**. This is the default, analyses all files, and persists all the new snapshot in the database. Old snapshots are not deleted, but, as stated in the docs (mentioned above) source code files that refer to the previos version are deleted.
- **preview analysis**. This is described like a full analysis except it doesn't store the results in the database. The results are instead displayed on the console or stored locally as html files. What I see when I run this mode (SonarQube 6.1) is that it indexes *all* files, but then detects the ones that have changed and finally runs a much quicker analysis (we can assume it reuses old analyses for files that have not changed). It checks the rules but doesn't work out the metrics.
- **incremental**. This is a bit misleading term. It is the setting used by the plugin SonarLint available to the IDEs (Eclipse, IDEA, Visual Studio, plus the command line tool) that restricts the analysis to the files that the developer has changed. Like the latter, it checks the rules only (no metrics). This is what they sometimes call "pre-commit" analysis, and I believe that it just analyses the files that are not yet committed (to do so, it queries the SCM that the developer has installed locally, Git or SVN). I also suspect that it cannot perform an analysis between two arbitrary commits.

Finally, the parameter that controls this behaviour is `sonar.analysis.mode` and in your version of sonar (5.1) corresponds respectively to the values `analysis`, `preview`, and `incremental`, while in new versions (5.3+) it must be set to `publish` and `preview` (there is also `issues` but I am not sure what it does, as they look a bit vague about and just tell that "*is a 'preview' equivalent intended for use by tools. and you should never need to use it manually*"; see [Analyzing Source Code - SonarQube-5.3](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE53/Analyzing+Source+Code))

Comment: Incremental Sonar Analysis
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6i4E5bhFj9s